# Control or set the emacs mouse button event polling rate?

Tags: mouse, events

I have been using artist-mode and noticed that even at moderate mouse movement speeds the mouse event polling rate (here for down-mouse-1) does not seem to keep up (so lines end up with scattered holes in them instead of being continous).

Is there a way to modify or increase the mouse (down) button event polling rate?

Comment: Pardon the practically irrelevant question, but whatever do you use `artist-mode` for? I was under the impression that `artist-mode` was one of those cute useless things that someone coded up when they were bored.

Comment: Well, I was going to try to make a note taking more based on artist-mode, like a simplified ascii based OneNote/Sketchnote; and then not having gaps in your writing would be better.

Comment: Ah. Good luck then.